# creating self-contained job postings component

Tags: javascript, asp.net

we have a job postings page on our web site. Our clients would like to include this job postings page on their web site. This way applicants can directly go to the client site to apply for the jobs rather than being redirected to our site. But when they apply for the job, the information will be saved in our system. How could we achieve this? One way would be to use iframe. But I am not sure if it would be efficient.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/

Answer (score 0):

A client-side widget that makes AJAX calls to your systems would work fine.